# Exist on .NET any way to detect if a Monitor with VGA plug is still plugged-in?

Tags: .net, monitor, vga

That's all, I want to know if someone unplug the monitor and take several actions, any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not tried by myself, but I think you can listen for WM_DEVICECHANGE and check for System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens collection changes.